# Converting SCORM.js to work with Unity 5

Tags: javascript, hashtable, unity-game-engine, scorm

I am trying to get SCORM 1.2 working with our Unity 5 WebGL project.

I thought I would introduce the SCORM code gradually; Here's the code I'd like to 'translate' so it works in Unity:

```
var vault = {};                             //vault 'namespace' helps ensure no conflicts with possible other "SCORM" variables
vault.UTILS = {};                           //For holding UTILS functions
vault.debug = { isActive: true };                   //Enable (true) or disable (false) for debug mode

vault.SCORM = {                             //Define the SCORM object
    version:    null,                               //Store SCORM version.
    handleCompletionStatus: true,               //Whether or not the wrapper should automatically handle the initial completion status
    handleExitMode: true,                       //Whether or not the wrapper should automatically handle the exit mode
    API:{handle: null, isFound: false},             //Create API child object
    connection: { isActive: false },                //Create connection child object
    data: { completionStatus: null, exitStatus: null},  //Create data child object
    debug:{}                                        //Create debug child object
};
```

When I use that code, as is, I'm told by Unity that `'Utils' is not a member of 'Boo.Lang.Hash'`

OK. I was told I should use Hashtables instead of plain ol' javascript ojects. So here's what I've got so far:

```
var vault:Hashtable = new Hashtable();              //vault 'namespace' helps ensure no conflicts with possible other "SCORM" variables
vault['UTILS'] = new Hashtable();                   //For holding UTILS functions
vault['debug'] = new Hashtable();                   //Enable (true) or disable (false) for debug mode
vault['debug']['isActive'] = true;

vault['SCORM'] = {                                      //Define the SCORM object
    version:    null,                               //Store SCORM version.
    handleCompletionStatus: true,                   //Whether or not the wrapper should automatically handle the initial completion status
    handleExitMode: true,                           //Whether or not the wrapper should automatically handle the exit mode
    API:{handle: null, isFound: false},             //Create API child object
    connection: { isActive: false },                //Create connection child object
    data: { completionStatus: null, exitStatus: null},  //Create data child object
    debug:{}                                        //Create debug child object
};
```

But now Unity throws the following error:

```
Type 'Object' does not support slicing
```

....at the `vault['debug']['isActive'] = true;` line.

So - How do I add a property to a Hashtable nested in a variable?

Comment: Unity's "JavaScript" is not actually JavaScript; it's actually cross-compiling that to Boo, which is then run on Unity's modified .NET CLR. Trying to get SCORM running in Unity is going to be very, very hard. It would probably be easier to run SCORM and Unity separately on the browser, then get them communicating through APIs.

Comment: This page: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html is being very informative but I'm getting a 'EntryPointNotFoundException' error. The research continues...

Comment: I don't work with Unity, but I'll take a moment to remind you the library is not named SCORM.js, it's the Pipwerks SCORM Wrapper, which was renamed by someone in your company. https://github.com/pipwerks/scorm-api-wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following this page's advice:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

It suggests loading your external .js files as normal into the containing html file (You have to set up a custom WebGL html template to do this) and then you can call those .js functions from C#, using:

```
Application.ExternalCall("functionName", "parameter");
```

You can also call C# functions in script components of GameObjects, from the external .js file, with:

```
SendMessage (GameObjectName, 'functionName', 'parameter');
```

So, I've encapsulated all of the direct SCORM interaction in the SCORM.js file - it makes all the LMSSetValue('cmi.objectives.... and LMSGetValue("cmi.core.lesson_status... updates and manages which objectives have previously been completed. Unity just tells SCORM which objectives it should initialise. All working well.

Sorted!

Comment: Yeah Unity's JavaScript interface wasn't like Flash so your mainly limited to just sending the message and having to push another call back into unity to get the result.  Its been a year or more since I looked into it but most the base examples just auto complete or do the "I was here" approach to SCORM.